# Why am I getting “ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0”? (array of string)

Tags: java, arrays, stored-procedures

I have in my code a procedure like this:

```
public void setawal(ArrayList<String> edge, String[] nodeforsub, int sizes){
    size=sizes;
    jumedge=new String[size];
    totalsubedge=new String[size];
    hasiljumedge=new String[size];
    hasilsubedge=new String[size];
    for(int j=0;j<edge.size();j++){
        if(jumedge[0]==null){
            jumedge[0]=edge.get(j);
        }else{
            jumedge[0]=jumedge[0]+":"+edge.get(j);
        }
    }
    urutan=new int[edge.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<edge.size();i++){
        urutan[i]=i;
    }
    node=nodeforsub;
    getsub(size, node, jumedge, totalsubedge, hasilsubedge, urutan);
}
```

in my project, two classes will access this procedure, when the first class accesses this procedure it works properly, but when the second class accesses this procedure, it showed this error message:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

How can I fix it?

I know the problem is when the second class tries to access `jumedge[0]`, but I am  confused why for first class it can access it properly?

Comment: because you are trying to access the first element of an array which doesn't contain any elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the `jumedge` array depends on the value of the `sizes` parameter passed to `setawal`. If you are passing `0`, the array will be empty and `jumedge[0]` will throw the exception.

This explains why some calls to this method throw an exception while others don't.

BTW, if you are only using the first element of the `jumedge` array, you don't need it to be an array. A single String will suffice. I don't know what the `getsub` method does with the `jumedge` array, but since you only set `jumedge[0]`, you can pass a single String to that method.